# How can I speed up this query? Is this 'too-normalised'?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, normalization

This is plausibly the longest query in history posted to SO.
Essentially I would like to know if this is the right idea for the query needed to do what I want, and given that it is extremely slow, how I would go about speeding it up.

I have been reading about data normalization etc, and perhaps this is too normalized? Given that a user can have hundreds of thousands of items, I need the quickest way of executing this, and it scaling.

I have six tables

```
--
-- Table structure for table `emails`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `emails` (
  `ID` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `sent` smallint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=5062 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `ips`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ips` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7534 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `user_items`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_items` (
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Allows sorting by last added..',
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `owner` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `folder` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `version` int(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `folder` (`folder`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10431 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `data`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data` (
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `info` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inserted` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `version` int(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `inserted` (`inserted`),
  KEY `version` (`version`),
  KEY `name_version` (`name`,`version`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7207 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `data_emails`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data_emails` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `version` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `time` int(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `version` (`version`),
  KEY `name_version` (`name`,`version`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9849 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `data_ips`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data_ips` (
  `ID` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ns_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `version` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `time` int(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `version` (`version`),
  KEY `name_version` (`name`,`version`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=17988 ;
```

What i need to achieve is as follows. I need to get each user_item and get the data, emails, and ips associated with it. user_items links to data, data_emails, and data_ips by the columns 'name' and version.

data_emails and data_nameservers link to emails and ips respectively with email_id/ip_id = ID

Because multiple joins result in row multiplication I have had to use nested subqueries. Because a user can have multiple emails and ips associated with an item I have used group_concat to group all that particular row.. I then explode this column in my PHP - this in itself seems inefficient, but I see no other way of doing it?

I have had a play with indexes, but because of the complicated joins and the fact I am pretty new to this I am unsure what indexes to have. Could anyone suggest indexes and explain them?

```
SELECT user_items.ID, user_items.name, user_items.update,data.*, x.emails,
    x.e_status, y.ip, x.email_counts, y.ip_counts
FROM user_items
    LEFT JOIN data AS data
        ON (data.name = user_items.name AND data.version = user_items.version)
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT data_emails.name, data_emails.version,
            GROUP_CONCAT( b.email SEPARATOR ',' ) as emails,
            GROUP_CONCAT( b.sent SEPARATOR ',' ) as e_status,
            GROUP_CONCAT( b.email_count SEPARATOR ',' ) as email_counts
        FROM data_emails 
            LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT emails.ID, emails.email, emails.sent, data_emails.name,
                    data_emails.version, data_emails.email_id,
                    COUNT(data_emails.ID) as email_count
                FROM data_emails 
                    LEFT JOIN emails ON (data_emails.email_id = emails.ID)
                GROUP BY data_emails.email_id
            ) b ON (data_emails.email_id = b.ID) 
        GROUP BY data_emails.name 
    ) x ON (data.name = x.name AND x.version = user_items.version) 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT data_ips.name,data_ips.version,
            GROUP_CONCAT( c.ip SEPARATOR ',' ) as ip,
            GROUP_CONCAT( c.ips_count SEPARATOR ',' ) as ip_counts
        FROM data_ips 
            LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT ips.ID, ips.ip, data_ips.name, data_ips.version,
                    data_ips.ip_id, COUNT(data_ips.ID) as ips_count
            FROM data_ips 
                LEFT JOIN ips ON (data_ips.ip_id = ips.ID)
                GROUP BY data_ips.ip_id
            ) c  ON (data_ips.ip_id = c.ID) 
        GROUP BY data_ips.name
    ) y ON (data.name = y.name AND y.version = user_items.version)
WHERE user_items.folder = '2'
GROUP BY user_items.name
```

For completeness, the output of Explain on the query is as follows:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+----------------------+--------------+---------+--------------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type |    table    |  type  |    possible_keys     |     key      | key_len |                    ref                     | rows  |              Extra              |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+----------------------+--------------+---------+--------------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | user_items  | ref    | folder               | folder       | 4       | const                                      |  1139 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | data        | ref    | version,name_version | name_version | 261     | gua.user_items.name,gua.user_items.version |     1 |                                 |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>  | ALL    | NULL                 | NULL         | NULL    | NULL                                       |  5591 |                                 |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived4>  | ALL    | NULL                 | NULL         | NULL    | NULL                                       |  5443 |                                 |
|  4 | DERIVED     | data_ips    | ALL    | NULL                 | NULL         | NULL    | NULL                                       | 16301 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  4 | DERIVED     | <derived5>  | ALL    | NULL                 | NULL         | NULL    | NULL                                       |  7533 |                                 |
|  5 | DERIVED     | data_ips    | ALL    | NULL                 | NULL         | NULL    | NULL                                       | 16301 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  5 | DERIVED     | ips         | eq_ref | PRIMARY              | PRIMARY      | 4       | gua.data_ips.ns_id                         |     1 |                                 |
|  2 | DERIVED     | data_emails | ALL    | NULL                 | NULL         | NULL    | NULL                                       | 10138 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | <derived3>  | ALL    | NULL                 | NULL         | NULL    | NULL                                       |  5061 |                                 |
|  3 | DERIVED     | data_emails | ALL    | NULL                 | NULL         | NULL    | NULL                                       | 10138 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  3 | DERIVED     | emails      | eq_ref | PRIMARY              | PRIMARY      | 4       | gua.data_emails.email_id                   |     1 |                                 |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+----------------------+--------------+---------+--------------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: I think there's a trailing `"` in the query (edit is too short and I can't do it myself)

Comment: As you only need `user_items` having folder `2` filter out those records and then apply `join`....

Comment: Well this query will be modified depending on the specific criterion of a given search - it wont alwats be folder 2. None - the less, could you clarify?

Comment: Surely your documentation or a textbook on database systems can explain indices. That said, a rule of thumb is "index every column used in a `WHERE` or an `ON` clause". I'd also consider avoiding all those subqueries and dealing with duplicate rows some other way if that helps performance.

Comment: Yea - you absolutely need to look into more indexes - specifically on data_emails and data_ips

Comment: Am I correct to think that the subqueries are what creates these temporary tables, and that in temporry tables index cannot be used? Millimoose - i have not found any other way of doing this without subqueries.. any thoughts?